# SQL - Unable to search 9 digit number from ntext datatype (Body of email)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help me in getting the correct result.
In sql table I have body of email(ntext), which has a 9 digit number. I not able to search the number, whereas same I am able to achieve from subject (nvarchar).

Query:

```
(CASE WHEN isnumeric(SUBSTRING(MsgBody, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', MsgBody), 9))=1 
--and LEN(SUBSTRING(MsgBody, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', MsgBody), 9))= 9
--and SUBSTRING(MsgBody, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', MsgBody), 9) not like '%[^0-9]%' 
--and SUBSTRING(MsgBody, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', MsgBody), 9) like '9%'
THEN SUBSTRING(MsgBody, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', MsgBody), 9) ELSE 
NULL END)
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for the first number and checking if it + next 8 characters can be converted into a number. What you should be using is patindex with 9 digits:

```
patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', MsgBody)
```

Comment: Well I am searching a 9 digit number starts with digit 9.

Comment: @Victor Well then have just 9 as the first character instead of [0-9]?